# Fish shell syntax highlighting looks weird in byobu-screen

Tags: macos, gnu-screen, byobu, fish

When I am in plain fish shell, a command is highlighted like so:

[image]

but when I am in `byobu-screen` and type the same thing, I get:

[image]

When I do a `fish_config` and look at my color palette, nothing is set to that darker blue color.

Note: I am on Mac OS X 10.9.1, and Byobu version 5.69 installed via Homebrew.

Comment: Okay, switching to `byobu-tmux` seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's because screen by default on OSX is only 8 colors, while fish wants to use 256 (it's actually not related to byobu, which is why it works when you switch to tmux).

To get it to work, you'd need to recompile screen with 256 color support. You could do something like this:

> git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/screen.git
>
> cd screen/src
>
> ./autogen.sh
>
> ./configure --enable-colors256
>
> make
>
> sudo make install
>
> cp screen /usr/local/bin/ # this should have precedence over the default screen in yr path

congrats on the engagement ;)

Answer (score 4):

Byobu now defaults to tmux (or at least, it does on Ubuntu). Append this to `~/.byobu/profile.tmux`:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```